# Bind command on IsChecked RadioButton property

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, command

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 5 and I need to bind a Command to IsChecked radioButton property.
How can I do this?
I tryed to add a behavior on IsFocused event, since IsChecked event doesn't exist, like so, but nothing happens:

```
<RadioButton.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="IsFocused" Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}" CommandParameter="V"/>
</RadioButton.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a command upon state change then you can use the event [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#respond-to-radiobutton-state-changes)

```
<RadioButton>
    <RadioButton.Behaviors>
         <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged" Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}" CommandParameter="V"/>
     </RadioButton.Behaviors>
</RadioButton>
```